# host html pages on shiny-server

Tags: r-markdown, shiny-server

I have used a combination of shiny and rmarkdown to build a website, in which the shiny app makes the search feature filtering results from a large database. Every result is linked by name to a detailed page where more information is provided. In practice, the app returns a result table in which each row of the name column is a link to the specific info page.

It seems however that shiny-server (installed on our server) does not allow hosting of html pages, so the link to the info page is broken -Not Found .

Alternatively, I am trying to render the info-page as a general rmarkdown page that is rendered with result-specific information every time it is called. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to pass down information through a link to a general rmarkdown document. In practice, what I want to implement: clicking on the result 'My result', a generic .rmd document is called and the same link passes down the name 'My result' to the .rmd so that it can retrieve 'My result'- specific information before being knitted.

Is there a solution to this using shiny-server?

Thanks,

Edith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shiny-server by default does not allow browsers to access content hosted in its directories. Content that needs to be made available can be hosted in a 'www' folder that is not indexed in the file path.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/hosting$20HTML$20pages$20on$20shiny-server%7Csort:relevance/shiny-discuss/eszrQJCbM_U/N7fpNEoMAwAJ